# What is the difference between git pull and git reset --hard origin/<branch>?

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull

I find the latter to be faster than the first, so I usually do that after `git fetch` whenever I need to sync my local branch with the remote. What is the difference?

Comment: `git pull` fetches from remote repositories, `git reset` deals with the local tree. How are they even comparable?

Comment: if your local branch differs from remote, `git pull` does the merge. `git fetch` with `git reset --hard` only checkouts it.

Comment: As a *very* loose analogy, think of `git pull` (which is `git fetch` followed by `git merge`) as: move me to a new address, taking all my possessions. Think of `git fetch` followed by `git reset --hard` as: burn all my possessions, then set me up at the new address. Since the houses come furnished, if you have no possessions of your own, the result is the same. But if you *do*, well...

Comment: `git stash` - I don't have any possessions.. :-)

Comment: @hurturk or, just burn all my possessions.

Comment: @zerkms Sun and Moon are totally different things, but they are comparable in the sense that they give light to us.

Comment: @technophyle I think you need to read what `git reset` and `git fetch` do. Or answers.

Comment: @zerkms I did sir, and I understood them.

Comment: @technophyle if you still think `git reset` and `git fetch` have anything in common - you're not understanding it well.

Comment: @zerkms man, read the question again. I'm not asking if `git reset` and `git fetch` have something in common. I'm asking about two specific actions.

Comment: To rephrase my question - what is the difference between `git pull` and `git fetch -> git reset --hard HEAD`, because the result is the same for the working copy? (of course, when there is no unstaged changes, and there is no fork) And I think this question is perfectly valid.

Comment: @technophyle the question is "What is the difference between git pull and git reset --hard origin/<branch>?". I copied it exactly. And the answer is - `git pull` and `git reset` have nothing in common. "because the result is the same for the working copy?" --- the result is totally not the same. I can easily make up repositories that would produce dramatically different results for both commands.

Comment: @zerkms And you don't read question descriptions, do you?

Comment: I totally do. `git pull` makes no sense after `git fetch` either.

Comment: @zerkms I recommend you to read the question and the answers and our conversation history before making assumptions. All the voters wouldn't be that stupid.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The following commands:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/<branch>
```

will discard all local changes.

Where as:

```
git pull
```

Which is exactly the same as:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/<branch>
```

will attempt to preserve local changes.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ git pull                        
# takes the latest changes of origin/branch (exists both local & remote changes)

$ git reset --hard origin/branch  
# replace your local with origin's branch history (discard local changes)
```

**Example:** Say, we have two commits in local `A`, `B` and remote has two commits `A`, `C`. Now if you pull then your local contains `A`, `B`, `C` unlike if *reset* then your local will have `A`, `C` not `B`.

Answer (score 3):

These two commands mostly used for different situations.

`git pull` pull (fetch & merge) changes from remote to local, especially other push commits to remote and you want these commit apply on your local branch.

`git reset --hard origin/branch` is force to make your local branch point to the commit where origin/branch is pointing to. It’s usually for the situation you want to abandon the local changes you made and keep the local branch as remote status.

Answer (score 0):

They are completely different in what they do:

`git pull`:
Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.

With `git reset --hard origin/branch` Git will:

- Make your current branch (typically master) back to point at `<SOME-COMMIT>`.
- Then make the files in your working tree and the index ("staging area") the same as the versions committed in `<SOME-COMMIT>`.

**Note**:
it's always worth noting that `git reset --hard` is a potentially dangerous command, since it throws away all your uncommitted changes. For safety, you should always check that the output of git status is clean (that is, empty) before using it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are getting a source update is more important than your performance concern. You need to utilize them for specific cases. I can provide you two examples:

- `git reset --hard ...` can be used for updating code in production if
  you often find yourself modifying production code for
  debugging. That usually happens on early stage of a project
  deployment with lazy thoughts.
- `git pull` is most accepted way of getting new commits and it
  usually makes sense you won't have huge local changes. If your commit periods are longer with more people on
  same branch, you may eventually have a gut feeling to do `git pull --rebase` or
  fetch first then compare.

Git can be explicit for very specific needs of your development style, you can discover them on the road. Performance shouldn't be concern at all once you are happy your work is safe.